# How to recover data to a database from the validation of a form in vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I created a promo code form when I paid for an item, but after filling out the form and clicking "Update", I get an error in the console. My request does not leave.
However, when I replace in the controller:

```
$couponDs = ModeratorPromoCodes::where('promo_code', $request->promo_code)->first();
```

by

```
$couponDs = ModeratorPromoCodes::where('promo_code', 'azerty03')->first();
```

I have a feedback in my console and my output is filled correctly.

The error code is :

```
POST http://dev.xxxxxxxxx.local:8000/fr/studio/coupon 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ VM6522:1
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:16140
xhrAdapter @ app.js:15974
dispatchRequest @ app.js:49732
Promise.then (async)
request @ app.js:49209
Axios.(anonymous function) @ app.js:49229
wrap @ app.js:15763
updatePromoCodes @ app.js:59090
invoker @ app.js:18239
fn._withTask.fn._withTask @ app.js:18038

----
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (app.js:16165)
    at settle (app.js:49281)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:16039)
```

**Route in web.php**

```
Route::post('/coupon', 'CouponController@submit')->name('coupon.submit');
```

**page.blade.php - *Input Form***

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input v-model="promoCodesOptions" v-on:keyup.enter="updatePromoCodes" name="promo_code">
                        <button type="submit" v-on:click="updatePromoCodes">Update</button>
                        <p>Reduction code is <i><b>@{{ promoCodesOptions }}</b></i></p>
              </label>
</form>
```

**page.blade.php - *Output code***

```
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              @{{ reduction }}
              <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">- @{{ output }} €</span>
</li>
```

**CouponController**

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Coupon;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use App\Models\ModeratorPromoCodes;

    class CouponController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function submit(Request $request)
        {   
            //$data = $request->all();

            $couponDs = ModeratorPromoCodes::where('promo_code', $request->promo_code)->first();

            //$couponDs = ModeratorPromoCodes::findOrFail(request('product'));

            return response()->json([
                'code' => $couponDs->promo_code,
                'discount' => $couponDs->discount(100)
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**VueJS code part**

```
    ...
    data () {
           return {
                pricingModal: {
                    display: false,
                    prices: [],
                    total: 0
                },
                paymentModal: {
                    display: true,
                    records: false,
                    prices: [],
                    extras: null,
                    promoCodesData: null,
                    hourly_rate_activated: false,
                    hourly_rate: null,
                    fees: null,
                    total: 0,
                    service_rates: []
                },
                paymentOptions: null,
                promoCodesOptions: null,
                couponDatas: [],
                output: '',
                reduction: ''
            }     
    },

    methods: {
            updatePromoCodes: function (value) {
                event.preventDefault();
                let currentObj = this;
                axios.post(route('studio.coupon.submit')).then(response => {
                    let data = response.data;
                    console.log(data);
                    //currentObj.output = 'response.data';
                    currentObj.reduction = 'Reduction';
                    currentObj.output = data.discount;
                    this.paymentModal.total = this.paymentModal.total + data.discount;
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });


                this.paymentModal.promoCodesData =  null;
                this.paymentModal.promoCodesData = value;

                this.paymentModal.total = this.paymentModal.total + data.discount;
            },
    }
```

Comment: check your error log for the 500 error...

Comment: @flame, in laravel log ??

Comment: yes it should have logged an error. If it has not, that means the error took place before laravel was setup.

Comment: The error log in the question is of no use. The server throws the 500 error and not the frontend.

Comment: {message: "Undefined index: coupon_code", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.xxxxxxxxxx.local/app/Http/Controllers/CouponController.php"
line: 52
message: "Undefined index: coupon_code"

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit is that the promo code you are searching for does not exist. In that case, `$couponDs` is `null`. You then try to access `promo_code` and a method `discount` on a non-object. Instead, check if you actually found a promo code, and act accordingly.

N.B. I normally use `$request->get('promo_code')`. I am not 100% sure that `$request->promo_code` works as you expect, but since Laravel works a lot with magic getters and setters it would not surprise me that it does actually return what you expect. You can dump this variable to see what it returns.

---

Edit: After your comment, I noticed that you are calling `axios.post(..)` without sending any data. You just call it with your route. Instead, you want to be passing the data in the second argument of that method:

```
axios.post(
  route('studio.coupon.submit'),
  {
    promo_code: this.promoCodesOptions
  }
).then(...)
```

You may run into the problem that Laravel is unable to parse the data you send it. Make sure to send the correct `Content-Type` header in your config as the third argument. For all request config options, see [the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).

Comment: I create in the controller
```$data = $request->all();```
and write
```$couponDs = ModeratorPromoCodes::where('promo_code', $data['coupon_code'])->first();```.

If I update with a normal form post, the new page print my result but when I test with axios in VueJS (ajax), I have the same error.